# MarkLogic 8 - SVC-EXTIME Time Limit Exceeded Error

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I processed 40+ million records in our `TEST database`, deleting bad records from a collection. That all ran in one shot over the course of several hours.

The data in `PROD` is the same but when I tried to run the same job, it times out giving me the error **SVC-EXTIME Time Limit Exceeded**.

What are the applicable timeout settings that could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the hardware in Prod the same as on Test? Was the hardware load the same when you ran your test? Differences could have varying levels of impact on performance. Also, timeout settings are configurable, so that's something to check if you haven't done so already.

Generally, the recommended procedure for large batch operations is to split them into smaller batches and spawn those jobs to the Task Server, which has a configurable queue. This is very easy to do in the latest versions of ML using `xdmp:spawn-function`.

```
xdmp:spawn-function(function() {
  xdmp:document-delete($uri), xdmp:commit() 
},
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
  <transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>
</options>
)
```

Comment: I ended up increasing some time limit settings, but the main fix was making my query more efficient. Didn't end up needing spawn, but good to know it's there.

Comment: Where is the option of changing the time limit?